# Can't change margin with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Here it is, the margin-left/right that do nothing.  Is it something to do with the widths?  It's going to be a left and right column web page, still need to add a line in the middle somehow too.

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.fleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    background:white;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: 6cm;
}

.fright {
    float: right;
    background:white;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 6cm;
}
```

Also doesn't work

```
.wrap {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto
margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.fleft {
float:left; 
width: 50%;
background:white;
height: 1000px;


}

.fright {
float: right;
background:white;
height: 1000px;
width: 50%;

}
```

Comment: W/o seeing your markup, I imagine combining margins and opposing floats is going to get wierd...

Comment: Also provide your html code here...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the space between the number and property value of margin. e.g.:

```
margin-left: 6cm;
```

[Otherwise it would be invalid property value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF7lN.png)

Comment: Still an issue with it deleting one of the containers

Answer (score 0):

Space are not alowed in css property value declaration Like this `margin-left: 6 cm;`.

worng Declaration rules.

```
margin-left: 6 cm;
```

Correct sysntax:

```
margin-left: 6cm;
```

Comment: Not the issue anymore.